# How to train tesseract to recognize small numbers in low DPI?

Tags: image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I get data from video so there is not way for me to rescan the image, but I can scale them if necessary.

I do have only a limited number of characters, `1234567890:`, but I have no control over the dpi of the original image or the font.

I tried to train tesseract but without any visible effect, the test project is located at https://github.com/ssbarnea/tesseract-sample but the current results are really bad.

Example of original image being captured:

[image]

Example of postprocessed image for OCR:

[image]

How can I improve the OCR process in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add some extra space at the edges of the image, sometimes it helps for tesseract. However, opensource OCR engines are very sensitive to the source image DPI.

Comment: Thanks, Nokolai. In fact I was trying tesseract because at this moment we are using a thrid party solution that is based on Abbyy but they do not provide training for it and in this case training would be mandatory in order to get good results - for the counter I need 100% accuracy, something that should be possible considering that there are only 11 possible characters.

Comment: I've just tryed to OCR your image in ABBYY FineReader 10 and it worked 100% accurate. Maybe this 3rd party solution is based on the old versions of ABBYY products? Can you tell me what exatly you are using?

Comment: Yes, it's working in 90% of the cases, and with manual repair of the output I can get up to 98% accuracy. Still I need a 100% solution.

Comment: @sorin, Actually [abby provides training](http://finereader.helpmax.net/en/advanced-features/recognition-with-training/training-user-patterns/)

Comment: @sorin, try and see if [this](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_recognize_only_digits?) improves accuracy for tesseract

Comment: @nikolay I solved the problem by implementing my own OCR that uses image comparison using scipy. It was able to obtain 100% accuracy for digits.

Comment: @sorin How did you train your own OCR ?